# URL does not change after clicking the search button with post method

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I reach to a page which has URL parameters.
e.g http://127.0.0.1:5000/?A=ABC123&B=44444&C=hello

When I click on search button, with some search string, with form method = post, it searches but has the same URL, which has values from the previous run.
It shows the search result but the parameter still has values from the previous run- http://127.0.0.1:5000/?A=ABC123&B=44444&C=hello

I want to remove the url parameters. After my search, the URL should be http://127.0.0.1:5000/

```
<form method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="search">
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

I expect the search button should clear the existing URL parameters.

Comment: you would have to use targe url in form `<form action="/" ...>` . If you don't use it then it uses current url as target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you can do a redirect to the request path which would clear the url params:

```py
@app.route("/search", methods=["POST"])
def search():
    ... get results ...
    redirect(request.path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use target url in `action` in `form`

```
<form action="/" ...>
```

If you don't use it then `form` uses current url as target and it keeps arguments in url.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print('args:', request.args)
    print('form:', request.form)
    return '''<form action="/" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>'''

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

With POST the data is not visible in the URL, by design. Checkout this resource [GET vs POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) and navigate to the bottom of the page's -- Compare GET vs. POST table.